# Non-abelian subgroup of PSL(2,C) is discrete?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

For context, I am following Sullivan's proof to the No Wandering Theorem, we have the following setup:

Let $S_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} S_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} S_3 \xrightarrow{f_3} S_4 \xrightarrow{f_4} ...$
be a chain  of analytic surjective maps between hyperbolic Riemann surfaces.

Let $\Gamma_\infty= \bigcup_i \Gamma_i $ where $\Gamma_i$ is the fundamental group of the hyperbolic Riemann surface $S_i$. We have $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma_2 \subset ... \subset \Gamma_\infty$.

The claim is that assuming one of the $\Gamma_i$ is non-abelian, we must have that $\Gamma_\infty$ is discrete. I'm not sure why this is, but here's what I figured so far:

We have to use the result "If a subgroup of PSL($2, \mathbb{C})$ contains no elliptic elements, it is either elementary or discrete."

Since $\Gamma_\infty$ is a subgroup of PSL($2,\mathbb{C})$, we can apply this result.

It is here where I don't know how to show that $\Gamma_\infty$ is not elementary and contains no elliptics elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We have to use the result "If a subgroup of PSL(2,ℂ)
 contains no elliptic elements, it is either elementary or discrete.": This "result" is simply false. Do you mean $PSL(2,{\mathbb R})$?

Comment: Also, the question makes no sense as written since you did not explain how the inclusions $\Gamma_i\to \Gamma_{i+1}$ are obtained. It is definitely possible to arrange these so that $\Gamma_\infty$ is nondiscrete, provided that each $\Gamma_i$ is infinite cyclic. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've added additional context to the question. In this context, aren't the fundamental groups subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Your question still makes no sense. Just read what you wrote. What is the logical connection between the 2nd and the 3rd paragraphs? As written, there is none.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a quick glance at the problem I'm referring to. It is on page 407, in the proof of proposition 1 : https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math627.S13/Sullivan-1985-Nonwandering.pdf

Comment: What Sullivan wrote is still ambiguous but way better than what you wrote; just read his proof carefully and you will find answers to your questions. My take is that he assumes that all the groups $\Gamma_i$ in question are Fuchsian, i.e. are discrete subgroups in $PSL(2,R)$.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. At the bottom of the page, he does remark the theorem that subgroups are either non-elementary, discrete, or contain elliptics. But you suppose he isn't deducing that they are fuchsian from this theorem?

Comment: The correct theorem that you will use is that an increasing union of discrete nonelementary subgroups is again discrete.

Comment: Oh right. So I've just got to figure out why all the subgroups are discrete and non-elementary.